# Angular make a default option selected

Tags: angular, forms, html-select

I am using angular5.
I want to make a option selected as default. But when I use the ngModel directive my code does not work anymore.

here is my code:

```
<select  class="form-control"  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [(ngModel)]="singleCar">
                    <option value="null"  selected='true' disabled>select car </option>
                    <option [ngValue]="Car"  *ngFor="let car of allCars">{{singleRole.name}}</option>
            </select>
```

does someone have a solution?

thx guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do this in the html:

```
<option [ngValue]="null">Select a car</option>
```

and in your component, you have to specify that the default value is null.

This works:

```
singelCar = null;
```

This does not:

```
singleCar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `option value="null"`. As by default, the first option value is set.

Comment: removing the value="null" doe not fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with the values and in some cases the `directives` that you've used.

Give this a try in your Template:

```
<select 
  class="form-control"
  [(ngModel)]="singleCar">
  <option 
    value="null"
    disabled>
    Select A Car
  </option>
  <option 
    [value]="car" 
    *ngFor="let car of allCars">
    {{car.name}}
  </option>
</select>
```

And in your Component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

  singleCar = { name: 'Car 4' };

  allCars = [
    { name: 'Car 1' },
    { name: 'Car 2' },
    { name: 'Car 3' },
    { name: 'Car 4' },
    { name: 'Car 5' },
  ];
}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nxg4h8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for your ref.

Comment: I have checked your example in your example 'Select A Car' is also not selected by default